# MySql test page

Tags: mysql

im using apache24
php5.6.8
and after installing them and making them both work 
i move to install mysql exactly how in the video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvt9P9HWWqg

first started this script on MySQL workbench below;

```
create database test_youtube;

use test_youtube;

create table users (
user_id mediumint unsigned auto_increment not null,
firstname varchar(40),
lastname varchar(40),
email varchar(50),
primary key (user_id) 
);

select * from users;
```

insert into users(firstname,lastname,email)
values ('barack',' obama','obama@yahoo.es');

before going anyfurther i modified a file in php follder called php.ini

then i create a phpmysqltest.php test page and put it in htdocts on my apacheserver folder

below is the code i used

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','sql2814','test_youtube'); // thats                the address, username, my pass and database name


// Insert query
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstname,lastname,email)
values ('Tom','Hanks','tommy@hotmail.com')";

if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) // if mysqli_query() function cant execute the         query PHP will display an error
{
echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($con);

}

else
{
//if it executed the query then do this
echo "It wooooooooooooooorked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! hhehehehehe";
}
```

i got these 3 errors

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmysqltest.php on line 2

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmysqltest.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmysqltest.php on line 11
Error:

any comments would help and

feel free to ask.?

Comment: Are you certain about your mysql connection information, like ip and user data? Cause it says they are wrong.

Comment: the mysql code was provided from a youtube video the link is in the post

Comment: i finally got it working, the password was incorrect.